How to check 5G NSA connection status on Samsung Galaxy?
I am aware about the different apps for checking 5G connection status on Android, the most useful of which I see CellMapper which says a lot of useful info about the current 5G connection. The one piece I am still missing is the deployment type of the 5G on the cell tower I am connected to. What I mean by deployment type is either SA (Standalone 5G) or NSA (non-standalone). Briefly speaking, it is the way 5G connection is established on the cellular infrastructure, either it uses the legacy 4G equipment (NSA) or new 5G equipment built from scratch (SA).
I wasn't able to find that info in CellMapper, nor in the ***#0011#** service menu

Is there any way to check this info? I am asking specifically for Samsung Galaxy but appreciate any Android-wide answer.
P.S. I have Samsung Galaxy A35 and I'm on Metro PCS carrier.

I would first check your phone (of which you did not mention the model) and your MNO  (also not mentioned) if they support 5G SA at all. I just read an article that only 124 of 588 5G networks worldwide support 5G SA at all.

thanks for the note, I updated the question and added the MNO and device info

I don't want anecdotal evidence, like you suggest. Every carrier constantly improves its network adding new base stations, and what was true yesterday is no longer valid today, new SA towers may be added already. I want a reliable software/hardware way to tell the parameters of 5G signal
